# How to configure environment variables per graphical session

Tags: environment-variables, display-manager, systemd-user

Consider the following setup:

1. I have GDM installed
2. I have multiple graphical sessions configured, both X11 and Wayland: **i3**, **sway**, **gnome**(x11).

I want to export different sets of environment variables for each of the graphical sessions. For example, I want to set `VAR_A=1` for **i3**, `VAR_A=2` for **gnome** and `VAR_A=3` for **sway**.

There are some more features I need to consider:

1. systemd-user units should inherit these variables. For example, if I have a service in `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/`, then it should be launched with `VAR_A=1` if I run it from **i3**.
2. It should be possible to switch between graphical sessions without manual reconfiguration. For example, if I would exit **i3** and launch **sway**, I wouldn't have to manually replace symlinks or recreate files.
3. It should be fault-tolerant solution. For example, if I'd accidentally pull of power cord while in **i3** and launch **sway** session afterwards, there wouldn't be a situation, when I'd get i3 environment variables on **sway** session.

I don't care, if these sets of variables would be loaded in non-graphical sessions (like ssh or tty). I'm also don't mind to change display manager, but I don't really enjoy starting graphical session  with `startx` or its wayland equivalents.

The only way I found is to tinker `*.desktop` files in `/usr/share/xsessions/` and `/usr/share/wayland-sessions`: wrap every executable in shell script, load variables from session-specific file in `$HOME/.config` and create symlink to this file in `$HOME/environment.d/`.

Is there any other solutions to this problem?